# I need some help with these jquery selection checkboxes

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

I have something like this:

```
<table>

<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"></input></td><td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="textInput1"></input></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"></input></td><td><input type="text" id="textInput2" disabled="disabled"></input></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"></input></td><td><input type="text" id="textInput3" disabled="disabled"></input></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4"></input></td><td><input type="text" id="textInput4" disabled="disabled"></input></td></tr>

</table>
```

I'm trying to enable the text inputs of the row where the checkbox being clicked is. Also more than one row must be selected upon checkbox selection. I tried using some basic jquery but it lacks by only enabling/disabling all the text inputs of all rows despite which checkbox being clicked. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
$("checkbox").click(function(){

if($(this).is(":checked")){
$("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", false);
 }else{
 $("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", true);  
 }  
}
```

Comment: what javascript do you have so far?

Comment: post some js you've tried and maybe we can help.

Comment: @Jonathan Fingland just added. Sorry I couldn't copy/paste but I have the code on my laptop and now I'm on my PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
   $(this).closest("tr").find("input:text]").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JWerg/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').attr('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {


 $(":checkbox").click(function(){
    var temp= $(this).attr("id");
    var a = temp.split("_");
    var i = a[1];

        if($("#checkbox_"+i).is(":checked")){
        $("#textInput_"+i).attr("disabled", false);
         }else{
         $("#textInput_"+i).attr("disabled", true);  
         }

         });

 });  
 </script>
```

and HTML like this:

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1"></input></td><td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="textInput_1"></input></td></tr>
```